# Prove $e^x \geq x+1$

Tags: inequality, continuity, exponential-function

I've tried finding a solution to this problem. I want to use the following definition of e

$e = \lim_{n \to\infty} (1+1/n)^n$

I have seen people argue with Bernoulli's Inequality, saying

$1+x \leq (1+x/n)^n \to e^x$

but how do I know $(1+x/n)^n \to e^x$? The arguments I've seen use continuity of the functions $x \to a^x$, where a is a real number, but the proofs I've seen of this use $e^x$ continuous and the proofs for $e^x$ continuous require $e^x >= x+1$...

I'm thankful for any help ! :)

Comment: There is a kind of arcane result that the sum of the even powers of the Taylor expansion is greater than the absolute sum of the odd powers.

Comment: If you assume the definition $e = \lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + (1/n))^{n}$ and then want to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + (x/n))^{n} = e^{x}$ then you need to have some other definition of symbol $e^{x}$. What's your definition of $e^{x}$ here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $e=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$, then
$$ e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1n\right)^{xn} $$
Let $n=\frac ux$ (which we can do so long as $x$ is constant):
$$\begin{align} e^x&=\lim_{u\to\infty} \left(1+\frac xu\right)^{u}\\
&=\lim_{u\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^u{u\choose k}\left(\frac xu\right)^k\\
&=\lim_{u\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^u{u\choose k}u^{-k}x^k\\
&=\lim_{u\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^u \frac1{k!}\frac uu\frac {u-1}u \cdots\frac{u-k+1}ux^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\\
&=1+x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{x^n}{k!}>1+x\end{align}$$

Comment: Do you mean $u=xn$?*

Comment: yes, thanks for the catch

Comment: With e=lim(n->\infty) (1+1/n)^n I get e^x = (lim(n->\infty)(1+1/n)^n)^x. Don't I need continuity of x->a^x, a real, to get the e^x = lim (n->\infty) (1+1/n)^(nx) ?

Comment: Is the last step still obvious if $x<0$?

Comment: @OliverBel It's obvious for $x\ge -2$ (monotonically decreasing alternating series).  After that point you can say $e^x\ge 0$ while $1+x<0$

Comment: @MadsFriis I suppose you're right, but from what I can tell the reasoning isn't circular.  See [this proof](http://www.karlscalculus.org/l6_0.html) of exponential continuity.

Comment: yea, I guess I dont really need $e^x \geq x+1$ to prove continuity, I just already wrote a really neat one using the inequality. Do you @TimRatigan see any way to prove the inequality with this aproach without using continuity ?

Answer (score 3):

*Proof of the inequality using the convexity*

Let $f(x)=e^x$ then we have $f''(x)=e^x\ge0$ so $f$ is a convex function and the equation of its tangent line at the point $x=0$ is $y=x+1$. What's the position of this tangent relative to the curve of $f$?

Comment: You've got a handy bag of tricks with many creative and useful approaches here at MSE! +1

Answer (score 0):

At $x=0$ we have $e^x=x+1$ and the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$ while the derivative of $x+1$ is just 1.

For $x>0$ we have $e^x>1$ since $\log(e^x)=x>\log(1)=0$. So $e^x$ grows faster than $x+1$ as $x$ increases.

For $x<0$ we have $e^x<1$ for the same reasons so $e^x$ goes down slower than $x+1$ as $x$ decreases.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac {n}{x}} \right)^{\frac{n}{x}} = e\text{, as} \frac{n}{x} \to \infty$$

Raising both sides to $x$ will give you what you want. Then just apply Bernoulli's Inequality as you've mentioned.